# antlr grammar: Lexer matches "impossible" rule

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I got this **parser grammar** with which I also want to use something similar to Javascript template-strings.

```
parser grammar Test;

options {
  tokenVocab = TestLexer;
}

definition: sourceElements? EOF ;

sourceElements: sourceElement+ ;

sourceElement: mapping ;


templateString: '`' TemplateStringCharacter* ('${' variable '}' TemplateStringCharacter*)+ '`' ;
fieldName: varname | ('[' value ']') ;
mapping: fieldName ':' ( '{' sourceElements '}'
      | variable ( '{' sourceElements '}' )? '?'?
      | value
      | array )
      ;

funParameter: '(' value? (',' value)*  ')' ;
array: '[' value? (',' value)* ']';
variable: (varname | '{' value '}' | '[' boolEx ']' | templateString) funParameter? ('.' variable)* ;
value: INT | BOOL | FLOAT | STRING | variable ;
varname: VAR ;
```

And this **lexer grammar**

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

WS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;
NEWLINE : [\r\n] ;
BOOL : ('true'|'false') ;
TemplateStringLiteral : TemplateStringCharacter*;
VAR : [$]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|[@] ;
INT : '-'?[0-9]+ ;
FLOAT : '-'?[0-9]+'.'[0-9]+ ;
STRING : '"' DoubleStringCharacter* '"' | '\'' SingleStringCharacter* '\'' ;
TEMPSTART : '${' ;
TEMPEND : '}' ;

TemplateStart : '`' -> pushMode(template) ;

/// Comments
MultiLineComment : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
SingleLineComment : '//' ~[\r\n\u2028\u2029]* -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

mode template;
TemplateVariableStart: TEMPSTART -> pushMode(templateVariable);
TemplateStringLiteral : TemplateStringCharacter* ;
TemplateEnd : '`' -> popMode;

mode templateVariable;
WS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;
All : [^}]+ ;
TemplateVariableEnd : TEMPEND -> popMode;

fragment DoubleStringCharacter : ~["\r\n] ;
fragment SingleStringCharacter : ~['\r\n] ;
fragment TemplateStringCharacter : ~[`] ;
fragment DecimalDigit : [0-9] ;
```

When I input this:

```
test: {
  abc: `Hello World`
}
```

The parsing tree looks like this:

```
(definition 
  (sourceElements 
    (sourceElement 
      (statement 
        (mapping 
          (fieldName 
            (varname test)
          ) : { 
          (sourceElements
            (sourceElement
              (statement mapping)
            ) 
            (sourceElement
              (statement
                (mapping abc : `)
              )
            ) 
            (sourceElement 
              (statement mapping)
            ) 
            (sourceElement 
              (statement 
                (mapping Hello)
              )
            ) 
            (sourceElement 
              (statement
                (mapping World `)
              )
            )
          ) 
          }
        )
      )
    )
  ) 
  <EOF>
)
```

And I get the error: line 2:8 no viable alternative at input 'abc:`Hello'

I don't understand, why it is even possible to match something like an empty **mapping** or a **mapping** like "World `" because a **mapping** would need to have a ":" in the middle. And why is the rule **templateString** not matching the whole "Hello World" from back tick to back tick?

**EDIT:**

After noticing that the Lexer wasn't regenerated when I thought it was I got errors like: "cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: ']'". So I had to move all implicit declarations to the lexer grammar. So I changed the code to this:

```
parser grammar Test;

options {
  tokenVocab = TestLexer;
}

definition: sourceElements? EOF ;

sourceElements: sourceElement+ ;

sourceElement: mapping ;

templateString: OpenBackTick TemplateStringLiteral* (TemplateVariableStart variable CloseBrace TemplateStringLiteral*)+ CloseBackTick ;
fieldName: varname | OpenBracket value CloseBracket ;
mapping: fieldName Colon (
      OpenBrace sourceElements CloseBrace
      | variable ( OpenBrace sourceElements CloseBrace )? IF?
      | value
      | array
    )
    ;

funParameter: OpenParen value? (Comma value)* CloseParen ;
array: OpenBracket value? (Comma value)* CloseBracket;
variable: (varname | OpenBrace value CloseBrace | templateString) funParameter? (Dot variable)* ;
value: INT | BOOL | FLOAT | STRING | variable ;
varname: VAR ;
```

And **lexer grammar**:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

OpenBracket: '[';
CloseBracket: ']';
OpenParen: '(';
CloseParen: ')';
OpenBrace: '{' ;
CloseBrace: '}' ;
IF: '?' ;
AND: 'AND' ;
OR: 'OR';
LessThan: '<';
MoreThan: '>';
LessThanEquals:   '<=';
GreaterThanEquals:   '>=';
Equals: '=';
NotEquals: '!=';
IN: 'IN';
NOT: '!';
Colon: ':';
Dot: '.' ;
Comma: ',' ;
OpenBackTick : '`' -> pushMode(template) ;

WS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;
NEWLINE : [\r\n] ;
BOOL : ('true'|'false') ;
VAR : [$]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|[@] ;
INT : '-'?[0-9]+ ;
FLOAT : '-'?[0-9]+'.'[0-9]+ ;
STRING : '"' DoubleStringCharacter* '"' | '\'' SingleStringCharacter* '\'' ;

/// Comments
MultiLineComment : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
SingleLineComment : '//' ~[\r\n\u2028\u2029]* -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

mode template;
TemplateVariableStart: '${' -> pushMode(templateVariable);
CloseBackTick : '`' -> popMode;
TemplateStringLiteral: TemplateStringCharacter ;

mode templateVariable;
WHS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;
All : [^}]+ ;
TemplateVariableEnd : CloseBrace -> popMode;

fragment DoubleStringCharacter : ~["\r\n] ;
fragment SingleStringCharacter : ~['\r\n] ;
fragment TemplateStringCharacter : ~[`] ;
fragment DecimalDigit : [0-9] ;
```

Now I get the error: 
**line 1:0 mismatched input 'test' expecting {, '?', '[', VAR}**
Which is strange, cause 'test' should be matched by **VAR**. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: This is the point where we really need to look at which tokens the lexer generates for your input. Looking at your lexer grammar, I agree that `test` should be a `VAR`, but clearly the lexer does not, so it'd be important to know what the lexer thinks `test` is. With your old code it would have been a `TemplateStringLiteral` (except that that would have matched more than just `test`), but with your current code I don't see anything else that matches. Try to run your lexer with `antlr4 TestLexer.g4 && javac *.java && grun TestLexer tokens -tokens` or iterate over the token stream in JavaScript.

Comment: In java does it work. In JS still not and I don't know how to output the same tokens as "grun TestLexer tokens -tokens" does. The documentation is not that good for JS. I tried `this.tokenStream = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(this.lexer);` But `this.tokenStream.tokens` only returned a list like: [ CommonToken {
    source: [ [UpsatLexer], [InputStream] ],
    type: 3,
    channel: 0,
    start: 0,
    stop: 3,
    tokenIndex: 0,
    line: 1,
    column: 0,
    _text: null }, ...]. I tried some other functions, but not all java-functions seem to be present in JS.

Comment: You can get the tokens via `lexer.getAllTokens()` and then you can print each one properly by calling its `toString` with the lexer as an argument. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sepp2k/934d2006da634c61a70976fb24e81afa)

Comment: I switched from a Backtick-Test to a normal DoubleQuote-Test with "Hello World"
Now I get from the lexer tokens a good result: [ '[@-1,0:3=\'test\',<26>,1:0]',
  '[@-1,4:4=\':\',<1>,1:4]',
  '[@-1,5:5=\'{\',<2>,1:5]',
  '[@-1,6:8=\'abc\',<26>,1:6]',
  '[@-1,9:9=\':\',<1>,1:9]',
  '[@-1,11:23=\'"Hello World"\',<29>,1:11]',
  '[@-1,24:24=\'}\',<3>,1:24]' ]
But still errors: line 1:0 extraneous input 'test' expecting {<EOF>, '?', '[', VAR}
line 1:6 mismatched input 'abc' expecting {'{', '[', '`', BOOL, VAR, INT, FLOAT, STRING}
line 1:24 mismatched input '}' expecting '{'

Comment: The <numbers> correspond to the token type they are supposed to. I passed the lexer as an argument but, only the numbers are printed.

Comment: Have you rebuilt the parser after rebuilding the lexer? Maybe the parser has a different idea of which numbers correspond to which tokens because it hasn't been updated since the last time you changed the lexer? That's the only thing I can think of if 26 is the number for `VAR`.

Comment: Yeah, the part about passing the lexer was nonsense (you can get rule names for parse trees by passing the parser to the tree's `toString`, but that doesn't work for tokens), you can use `lexer.ruleNames[tok.type]` to actually get the token type as a string, but if the numbers match that will just print `VAR` as well.

Comment: @sepp2k Thank you very much for all your help. Finally I could make it work. I had the wrong parser file included because of some renaming I did a while ago. But this was not causing the lexer error. This one I fixed by swapping the whole block from OpenBracket to OpenBackTick with the block from WS to STRING.

Answer (score 1):

There are two lexer rules in your default mode that can match a backtick: `BTICK` and `TemplateStart`. `TemplateStart` will switch to the `template` mode, but `BTICK` will not. Since `BTICK` comes first in your grammar, so it takes precedence. That means when the lexer sees a backtick, it will generate a `BTICK` token and not switch modes.

To fix this you should have only one lexer rule per mode that matches a backtick and that rule should change the mode.

> I don't understand, why it is even possible to match something like an empty mapping or a mapping like "World `" because a mapping would need to have a ":" in the middle.

When your input contains a syntax error, the generated parse tree can contain constructs that aren't actually valid either. When your input parses without errors, you'll get a tree that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now removed the BTICK rule and now use backticks simply with '`' (I also updated the question). But I still get the same output. Do you have another idea what it could be?

Comment: @MartinCup Can you post the tokens that are generated for your input? Your `TemplateStringLiteral` rule looks very suspicious (especially as you don't use it anywhere), so I suspect that it eats everything up.

Comment: I added them to the question. Strange is, I removed `TemplateStringLiteral`from both grammars now, but it is still is in the generated tokens.

Comment: @MartinCup I'm sorry, I meant which tokens the lexer generates for your specific input, not which tokens there are in general. Like the output of `echo '{abc: \`Hello World\`}' | grun Test definition -tokens`.

Comment: I always build the JS-Files with "java -Xmx500M -cp '/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH' org.antlr.v4.Tool  -Dlanguage=JavaScript -lib grammars -o lib -visitor -Xexact-output-dir grammars/Test.g4"
To use grun I need a Java file correct?
When I try to run "antlr4 grammars/Test.g4" I get a lot of errors like: "cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: ']'"

Comment: @MartinCup And you don't get that error when building for JavaScript? That sounds like there's actually an error in your grammar. That might also explain why `TemplateStringLiteral` was still there after you removed it from the grammar: the grammar is not actually compiling and the generated files remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I noticed only the Visitor and the Listener are newly generated, the Lexer is not. Thats probably because I had a combined parser and lexer file and just recently split it. So I got to somehow tell the generator to generate the lexer code too.

Comment: @MartinCup Yes, you need to run ANTLR on the lexer .g4 file first and then on the parser one.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my question. Maybe you have an idea why I get the error: line 1:0 mismatched input 'test' expecting {, '?', '[', VAR}